# Scheduling console application

Tags: c#, .net, console, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a .NET console application that needs to be scheduled trough Windows scheduler. Such console performs some network and database activities and write a logfile. The application work if run on Desktop/Command prompt but if I try to run it trough the scheduler it refuse to start. Another issue I faced is the write access to the app folder. Even if I set permissions to the folder containing application binaries to be wrote by 'Everyone' the app seems unable to create the log file and/or append data to it. The problem fixes if I run the application with Administrator priviledges (on desktop) but if I define the Activity in the scheduler to Run with higher privildegs this will not fix it anyway.

Comment: Its not uncommon these days that programs that create desktop interaction are blocked by the scheduler - especially on servers..

Comment: You would potentially be better off writing a windows service rather than a scheduled console application

Comment: @Kritner in the way you suggest I would have to manage the scheduling of the task by myself . Is there a way to create a single shot service that's scheduled by an external tool? I think this would not fix the write permissions faults issues anyway.

Comment: @BugFinder maybe I'm failing but a console application cannot iteract with desktop...

Comment: No chances of it having windows forms in the uses, no popup boxes, no nothing? what does your app do?

Comment: @BugFinder It connect to a mysql database, do some query, write some data to file (log), read some data from file (configuration) then send some email messages (but up to now this feature is disabled). All this  without interaction with user or output on the console.

Comment: any event messages to go with? UAC turned off? where is it writing to?

Comment: UAC is not turned off. As a first attempt the application try to create the logfile to a path where the options on the command line point to if it got an exception on creating it it fallback creating the logfile in C:\Windows\Temp\log.txt. Please note that If I run the app without admin priviledges trough command prompt it fallback and write to the log... if I run it trough the scheduler with or without admin priviledges it will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2452723
It seems that the "Start In" parameter of the Action should not contain quotes.
Of course the folder should be 'writetable' for the user assigned to the task.

Answer (score 1):

Best course of action is to create a Service account with admin privileges and schedule the task under such account and select the option to run  whether the user is logged on or off. 
This approach is even more relevant where Active Directory is in place.

Hope this helps,
Apex

Comment: I tried this creating a new user with admin priviledges but without luck. The command is still not executed and the problem seems to be again the write permissions on the application folder (btw the newly created user has been given full control permissions over this folder).
BTW I'm working in Windows 10 Home.

Comment: No i did not mean a user account. You need a specific service account. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739458(v=ws.10).aspx is your best bet (i doubt there's a windows 10 guide, but the idea is the same). Good luck, Apex.

Comment: Ok I see, of course on a Server I will do it this way but on a Win10 Home there's no other way to do it... afaik